# How to use left join to take all data from master table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can i take all data from EmniyetStok. For example EmniyetStok has 1000 rows and maching other table 200 rows. Below query returns to me 200 rows. But i wanna take all emniyetstok (all 1000 rows) . I used left join (for EmniyetStok) but it dows not work. i wanna take all rows of Emniyetstok (master table). if t.Quantity is null or  or empty, at the end of the query exeqution , it should be zero.

please dont remove: WHERE {0}  clouse i need after. after where , it should return 1000 rows. "WHERE  e.CustomerID = '0061004287' AND  t.SapContractNumber = '3120012161' " i will add.

```
SELECT 
s.MaterialNumber, 
sum(s.Stock) Stock,
dbo.getSapContractNumberBySapDeliveryNumber(s.SapDeliveryNumber) SapContractNumber,
s.BillTo,
s.Quantity
INTO #tmp
FROM Stok s
GROUP BY s.MaterialNumber, s.SapDeliveryNumber, s.BillTo, s.Quantity
-----------------------


-----------------------
SELECT
e.SapContractNumber [Anlaşma No],
c.ContractName [Anlaşma Adı],
e.CustomerId [Müşteri No],
cu.CustomerFullName [Müşteri Adı],
e.MaterialNumber [Ürün No],
sc.MaterialName [Ürün],
convert(decimal(10,2),avg(EmniyetStok)) [Emniyet Stok],
convert(decimal(10,2),avg(OrtalamaStok)) [OrtalamaStok],
convert(decimal(10,2),sum(Stock)) Stok,
convert(decimal(10,2),avg(e.ortalamastok) - sum(t.Quantity)) SiparisOnerisi
FROM EmniyetStok e
LEFT JOIN #tmp t 
ON t.MaterialNumber = e.MaterialNumber 
AND t.SapContractNumber = e.SapContractNumber 
AND e.CustomerID = t.BillTo 
LEFT JOIN Contracts c ON c.SAPContractNumber = e.SapContractNumber
LEFT JOIN Customers cu ON cu.CustomerID = e.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN StockCards sc ON sc.MaterialNumber = e.MaterialNumber
WHERE {0} 
GROUP BY 
e.SapContractNumber,
c.ContractName,
e.CustomerId,
cu.CustomerFullName,
e.MaterialNumber,
sc.MaterialName
HAVING sum(t.Quantity) < avg(e.ortalamastok) 

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause includes `#tmp.SapContractNumber` so the `LEFT JOIN` becomes an `INNER JOIN` on that basis. Also, you are performing a `GROUP BY` which in itself will probably limit the row count and then a `HAVING` which, as a filter, is designed to return less rows than the source table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the string:

```
HAVING sum(t.Quantity) < avg(e.ortalamastok)
```

You lose records when t.Quantity is null or e.ortalamastok is null.
Сorrect and check:

HAVING sum(ISNULL(t.Quantity, 0)) < avg(ISNULL(e.ortalamastok,0))